# How to UITest a cell' value of ListView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode-ui-testing, gui-testing

I have a note taking app. I have added 4 notes (Note 1, Note 2, Note 3, Note 4) as a part of app's UITest case. Now I would like to test few edge cases which are:

1. The ListView has exactly 4 cells.
2. Note 2 is on second cell.

   ```
    func test_notesVew_addNewMultipleNote_shouldSeeNewNotesInHomeScreen() {
       let addNewButton = app.navigationBars["Notes"].buttons["Add new note button"]
       addNewButton.tap()

       let collectionViewsQuery = app.collectionViews

       createNote(num: 1)
       addNewButton.tap()
       createNote(num: 2)
       addNewButton.tap()
       createNote(num: 3)
       addNewButton.tap()
       createNote(num: 4)

       // MARK: - Scenario: Validating added notes
       let cellCount = collectionViewsQuery.cells.count
       XCTAssertEqual(cellCount, 4, "After adding 4 notes, cell count should be 4")

       // MARK: - Scenario: Validating note's order
       //let noteOnSecondRow = collectionViewsQuery.element(boundBy: 1)
    }
   ```

How to access value or index of a specific cell of a ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commented solution is not looking for the second cell, it's looking for the second collectionView. The following should get you what you need:

```
let secondCell = collectionViewsQuery.cells.element(boundBy: 1)
let secondCellValue = secondCell.staticTexts.element.label
```